# How to disable SSL v 3.0 on Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website that is hosted on Microsoft Azure Websites. It runs only in HTTPS and has a IP certificate. How do I disable SSL v 3.0 protocol on an Azure Website and only allow TLS 1.x ?

The website is running Asp.Net MVC 5 and .Net framework 4.5

Comment: Keep in mind that you also have to keep an eye on any APIs you use, particularly when you have a library for speaking with that API. We just had to solve an issue last night (after this POODLE attack) where a third party library for that service specified SSL connections use SSL3, which was causing all those connections to fail. So even if you manage to forbid SSL3 for web requests, you still have to think about any API libraries you use.

Comment: I asked Scott Hanselman about this on twitter, and he in turn asked Nir Mashkowski. His response was, "This is a client issue, We are looking at server side mitigation for customers.". https://twitter.com/nirmsk/status/522423884922884097

Comment: It's a client *and* a server issue. Whilst both parties support it, there is a risk. As soon as one party *doesn't* support it, there's no more talk over SSL 3. Ideally you'd disable it on both client and server but Azure websites terminate SSL upstream of the site itself so you can't just configure your site to disable SSL 3.

Comment: If you happen to also use CloudFlare like me, they have already disabled SSLv3 at server level to protect, https://blog.cloudflare.com/sslv3-support-disabled-by-default-due-to-vulnerability/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update (11/1/2014): SSLv3 is now completely disabled on Azure Websites. You no longer need to install the Site Extension mentioned below.

---

You can now disable SSLv3 on Azure Websites. This [post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/) has the details.

Basically, you just need to install the [DisableSSLv3](http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/DisableSSLv3/) site extension into your site, and restart the site.

To verify that it's in fact disabled, try running:

```
curl -sslv3 https://{yoursite}.azurewebsites.net/
```

And make sure you get a 403.

Comment: We have installed the extension and restarted our websites but it seems as it still supports SSLv3.
We have tested our sites at both [poodlebleed.com](http://poodlebleed.com/) and [www.poodlescan.com](https://www.poodlescan.com/)

Comment: Can you please add comment to http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/, so it gets centralized there? Thanks.

Comment: We found that the problem was in our code with a connection to a third party plugin, which forced the use of SSLv3. Now your extension works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: I've installed also the extension but still supports SSLV3. could you please tell me how to know what prevents the extension to work properly?

Comment: Update: according to [the original blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/) there will be a general/actual fix soon:

> The changes will be rolling out through the week of Monday October 27th, 2014.

Comment: Please see update to answer, and try running tools like poodlescan again.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: SSL v3 is now disabled by default with Azure Websites, see [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/)**

This is currently not possible (server side) with Azure Websites.

But the Azure team is working on offering the option to disable SSL v.3 according to David Ebbo (@davidebbo) who is a Microsoft dev lead working on Azure Websites.

See conversions on twitter in the link below and response from David. (thanks to Jon Sagara)
https://twitter.com/nirmsk/status/522423884922884097

Comment: That's correct. We'll post an answer here when the option is available.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/) (see update), from October 27th 2014, SSL 3.0 is disabled through all Azure Web-Sites. So we don't need to take any actions! Yay!